# eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available (Python/ Brownie)

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, web3py, brownie

I am a beginner Dapp Developer. But I do have a good background in programming. I have started to learn blockchain from freecodecamp this week and I have learned the basics of BL and Solidity, and now I am deploying the Smart contracts with Brownie (A Python framework built on top of Web3). I can deploy with Ganache but however, but I can't with Rinkbey. I was using Infura API for deployment and did set the environments right (PRIVATE_KEY and WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID). Also please note that I have a valid eth address.

When I run the script it throws the below error

```
"ValueError: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available"
```

I did all sorts of searches about this error but I couldn't any proper answer. Some say the transaction needs to be signed by the PK and some say it's not supported by Infura.

I precisely followed all the steps from the instructor. I even cloned the Github code of the script from freecodecamp even though throws the same error. But It works fine with Ganache.

- https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/brownie_simple_storage/blob/main/scripts/deploy.py
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=432s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

Please help me to overcome this error, I am stuck for days!!

Answer (score 0):

`eth_sendTransaction` is not relevant for modern day Ethereum development. It's a server side function and legacy from 2014. It has been disabled on modern nodes.

[Instead please find out how to work and sign transactions with local accounts](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#read-a-private-key-from-an-environment-variable)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, also please note that I did mention that I found the solution that you gave. Anyhow, I didn't find a way to do it with Brownie. Do you know how to sign transitions with brownie?

Comment: Try asking in in Brownie Discord https://discord.gg/p4pp9GQx